# Drawing trees with xymatrix

Tags: graphs, xy-pic, trees

I would like to draw trees using xymatrix, however using for example

```
\xymatrix{\ar@{-}[dr] & & \ar@{-}[dl]\\ & \ar@{-}[d] & \\ & & }
```

returns the image

[image]

My problem with this is the fact that the edges don't join in the middle. Is there a way to correct to this (possibly not involving passing to tikz)?

Comment: Do you need to draw trees or graphs?  There are a couple of linguistic tree drawing packages based on `xypic` but they really assume you are drawing single rooted n-ary trees with downward branches, typically with node labels.

Comment: @AlanMunn I am drawing single rooted n-ary trees with upward branches, often with leaves labelled, and sometimes also some vertices. Do you know of any package that would suit my case? I tried looking around, but didn't find anything...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid TikZ particularly? But, there are `ps-` packages for drawing trees, which seem comparable to some of the TikZ packages. (Not **forest**, probably, but probably **tikz-qtree** etc.) At least, I believe so.

Comment: @cfr Well, I already more or less know how to do it in tikz, but it's usually a lot of work... I'm actually trying to write some macros to do this in tikz faster.

Comment: I would second @cfr 's suggestion. Drawing upwards trees with `tikz-qtree` or `forest` (both of which use `tikz`) is relatively trivial.   It's only the standard tree methods in `tikz` that are slow to input. These packages use a bracketed notation which is very fast to input.

Comment: Can you show us a more elaborate version of the kind of tree you need to draw?

Comment: You also might take a look at what can be done with `pst-tree`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you! That's what I meant, I think, when I said `ps-`. I always think of it as 'postscript', although that's a bit misleading in certain ways, I know.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud If you are trying to write macros in TikZ then (1) Why did you rule out a TikZ-based answer? (2) Why are you reinventing the wheel when there are such round, roly, spinny models available already?

Comment: @cfr Ok, maybe I phrased that wrong. What I didn't want was an answer like "draw them in tikz." I'm not against tikz-based libraries. For your second question, mainly the reason is that I don't know many tikz packages/libraries. Also, I have to draw stuff related to operad theory, so sometimes I would like to draw trees with labels in specific places, and to use them in math formulae and not as standalone drawings, and that's why I was trying to build some macros.

Comment: Maybe see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279924/macro-for-creating-trees-for-b-series-as-math-symbols. You can put labels anywhere you want if you use **forest** (or **tikz-qtree**), and as that question shows, you can certainly use these packages as the core of quite specialised macros for custom usage. Otherwise, you have to reinvent a lot of infrastructure because you are not just solving the issues specific to your needs, but all the issues involved in specifying and drawing bog-standard (and less bog-like) trees as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tree drawing package for linguistics based on `xypic` called `xyling`. It can do what you want, but since most linguistics trees assume node labels, and downward branches, drawing trees up will be a bit of hack.
The main syntax uses `xymatrix` underlyingly, and implements some node commands and a `\B` command to make branches. The optional argument to the `\B` command is an adjustment to extend the node upwards to the empty node above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xyling}
\begin{document}
\Tree{ \B{dr} & & \B{dl} \\
        &\B[6]{d}\\
        &  &\\
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with **forest**. It is straightforward, once you have styles defined for the kinds of trees you need, to apply them. Trees can then be specified *extremely* concisely.

In this case, we define a style `my tree` and then apply it to a tree as follows:

```
\begin{forest}
  my tree
  [Aardvarks
    [Agglomeration
      [
        [
          [Aggrandisement]
          [Artificiality]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Anticipation
      [Ants]
      [Ant-Eaters, tikz={\draw [densely dashed, ->, red] (.parent anchor) [out=45, in=135] to (!s.parent anchor);}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

To produce

[image: red in tooth and claw]

The longest part of this is the arrow showing the ant-eaters eating the ants. But if you often need to illustrate that nature is red in tooth and claw, you could easily set up a style for this and just say e.g.

```
      [Ant-Eaters, tooth and claw]
```

to achieve the same result. But this is probably not a standard feature of linguistic trees and unnecessary here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  my tree/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=north,
      child anchor=south,
      grow=90,
    },
    nice empty nodes up
  },
  nice empty nodes up/.style={% modified from page 52
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=south}}}{}}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  my tree
  [Aardvarks
    [Agglomeration
      [
        [
          [Aggrandisement]
          [Artificiality]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Anticipation
      [Ants]
      [Ant-Eaters, tikz={\draw [densely dashed, ->, red] (.parent anchor) [out=45, in=135] to (!s.parent anchor);}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```